# How To Center Your Opt-In Layout in OptimizePress?

Tags: wordpress

Every time I tried to create a new page (simple blank box) in the OptimizePress plugin
My layout always aligned to the left for some reason, And I want it in the center (like it should be).
BTW every element in the page is aligned to the center, But it changes nothing...
What should I do?
[example](http://screencast.com/t/lpRCaUmR8)

Comment: Do you have a URL we can look at?

Comment: @MatthewR. Here: http://lior-geva.com/teati/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason your responsive stylesheet is floating the center panel left instead of keeping it centered. If you shrink your browser down under 1008 pixels in width, you will see that it centers properly. If you remove this on line 3561:

```
.main-content { float: left; }
```

Inside of the media query:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1008px) { ... }
```

In the file:

```
/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/style.css
```

That will fix your issue.

Comment: Do I need to remove all of that content? ".main-content { float: left; }"

Comment: Technically, no. You can just get rid of the `float: left;`, but since there is nothing else in that selector, you can remove everything if you prefer.